# Spring Security - REST API - token vs. cookie

Tags: spring, spring-security, token

I have written a REST- API in Java and I have secured this API with Spring Security. The procedure is like this:

1. Frontend invokes /login RestService in Backend
2. Backend gives back token to frontend
3. at each REST- API Backend invokation the token has to be placed in header

This works fine, but I have read that it is also possible (with Node.JS/Passport.js/Express.js) that the session object with the cookie inside can be transfered out of the box without any custom code.

My question now would be if there is a better approach so that the frontend/client do not need to set the token into the header all the time for any request.

Comment: Use cookies (like the way you mentioned node.js, passport.js, express.js uses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually token based authentication has advantages over cookie based.

You can achieve this using middle-ware layer

Here is a good Post -  https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Answer (score 3):

Server side, I usually first check in the headers if there is an auth token. If not, I then check in the cookies as a fallback.

If you want to use cookies, then at your step 2, you need to add a [Set-Cookie header](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/HTTP_cookie#/Setting_a_cookie) to the response, so that browsers know they must store a cookie. Once done, no need to add a header client-side, since browsers will send cookies each request. You'll need to add a CSRF protection though ([here](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/) is a good example).